# Html - Overflow:hidden still takes space

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, overflow

I have a problem with a scrollable div. There's a div acting as a scrollable container (using a jquery plugin). The container has an overflow:hidden style. it works as expected, but i noticed that the browser has a scroll too, something which I want to prevent.

I know i can disable scrolling on the html body entirely, but i wish to avoid this since it means manipulation on resize which isn't really an elegant fix.

I know that the hidden overflow, contrary to a "display: none", still takes up space. what I'm looking for is a simple way to have my overflow "really" hidden.
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: overflow hidden means anything outside the size defined will not take up any space - I think your confusing it with visibility hidden

Comment: It sounds as if your plugin needs `overflow: hidden` property so it can add it's own custom scroll bar. Try disabling the plugin and applying an `overflow: auto` property to your container instead.

Comment: @antony: The plugin (mCustomScrollbar) does require overflow:hidden. However, even when I disabled it and moved to overflow: auto (or scroll) it still takes the same space in the page.

Comment: Have you set the height of the container? You need to give it a height.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or isolated code that reproduces this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another wrapper div around your container and add this style for that.

```
.wrapper{
   overflow: clip;
}
```